# Schengen visa entry

Tags: visas, schengen, germany

Hi I am Ashraf from Eygpt I have schengen visa type c multiple entry from Switzerland for 5 years I already used it 2 time for going to Switzerland but now I need to go for Germany to Hanover and its long traveling from Swiss so my question is that if I can go directly to German or I need to go throw Swiss?

Comment: I presume your citizenship is Egyptian?

Comment: Yes, you can travel directly to Germany.

Comment: Yes my citizenship is Eygpt and thank you for answers